# Python: how to use glob and wildcard to open CDF files

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, cdf

I'm trying to open multiple .cdf files and store them in a dictonary, but when I try to use wildcard within the `pycdf.CDF()` command, this error is returned: `spacepy.pycdf.CDFError: NO_SUCH_CDF: The specified CDF does not exist.`

The .cdf files have a set initial name (instrumentfile), a date (20010101) and then a variable section (could be 1, 2, 3, or 4). This means that I can't simply write code such as:

```
DayCDF = pycdf.CDF('/home/location/instrumentfile'+str(dates)+'.cdf')
```

I also need to change the names of the variables that the .cdf data is assigned to as well, so I'm trying to import the data into a dictionary (also not sure if this is feasible).

The current code looks like this:

```
dictDayCDF = {}

for x in range(len(dates)):
    dictDayCDF["DayCDF"+str(x)] = pycdf.CDF('/home/location/instrumentfile'+str(dates[x])+'*.cdf')
```

and returns the error `spacepy.pycdf.CDFError: NO_SUCH_CDF: The specified CDF does not exist.`

I have also tried using `glob.glob` as I have seen this recommended in answers to similar questions but I have not been able to work out how to apply the command to opening .cdf files:

```
dictDayCDF = {}

for x in range(len(dates)):
    dictDayCDF["DayCDF"+str(x)] = pycdf.CDF(glob.glob('/home/location/instrumentfile'+str(dates[x])+'*.cdf'))
```

with this error being returned: `ValueError: pathname must be string-like`

The expected result is a dictionary of .cdf files that can be called with names DayCDF1, DayCDF2, etc that can be imported no matter the end variable section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about starting with the following code skeleton:

```
import glob

for file_name in glob.glob('./*.cdf'):
    print(file_name)
    #do something else with the file_name
```

As for the root cause of the error message you're encountering: if you [check the documentation of the method you're trying to use](https://pythonhosted.org/SpacePy/autosummary/spacepy.pycdf.CDF.html), it indicates that

> Open or create a CDF file by creating an object of this class.
>   Parameters:
>
> pathname : string
>
> ```
> name of the file to open or create
> ```

based on that, we can infer that it's expecting **a single file name**, **not** a list of file names. When you try to force a list of file names, that is, the result of using `glob`, it complains as you've observed.

Comment: I jerry-rigged a basic if elif else loop based on os.path.isfile - if file exists then import the cdf, if not keep on going. There are a limited number of file endings for now but when I have time I will try and make the code a little nicer, starting with your suggestion.

Comment: If your file name pattern (that includes wildcard) is a valid one, then `glob.glob` will return all of the file names matching that pattern. Therefore, I don't think you need to use `os.path.isfile`. If it's in the list of the values returned by `glob`, then by design, it should exist (unless some other process deleted the very same file in the meantime, that is).